# Matlab - make function work with vectors and scalars

Tags: matlab, function, for-loop

I'm trying to write a function that can be a scalar and a vector. This function should handle scalars, column vector and row vector. My thought was that I try with a for loop but I'm not successful in my attempts.

```
function f=funk1(x);
for i =1:length(x)
 f=exp(-3*x(i).^2)-log(x(i)+0.6)+1/(x(i)-6);
end
end
```

This only return the last value of the vector (in my function) but I want it to return every value from my vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed indexing of f. Do that;

```
function f=funk1(x);
for i =1:length(x)
   f(i)=exp(-3*x(i).^2)-log(x(i)+0.6)+1/(x(i)-6);
end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe that I miss that! :)

Answer (score 3):

For this specific function you can [vectorize](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html), that is, do all computations element-wise at once without a loop. You only need to add a dot before `*`, `^`, `/` operators when applied between arrays (`log` and `exp` are element-wise already):

```
function f = funk1(x);
f = exp(-3*x.^2)-log(x+0.6)+1./(x-6);
end
```

Comment: Like always, overvectorising the solution ;) Good work!

Comment: @Adriaan Vectorizing is never "over"! :-P